# awk how to print column 1-4, rest with leading tabs between columns 4 and end of line, keeping the tabs

Tags: awk, tabs

I have a file that looks like this (1000's of lines):

```
blabla.xml 36 14601    lllpxl01\t\t\tselect 1 from dual
```

Between column4 and column5 there are tabs which I would like to keep.
My desired output would be:

```
blabla.xml,36,14601,lllpxl01,\t\t\tselect 1 from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

if the `\t\t\t` are 6 literal characters and really NOT meant to be 3 `<TAB>` chars

```
echo "blabla.xml 36 14601    lllpxl01\t\t\tselect 1 from dual" \
| awk '{
    # change a consecutive run of space chars to a single "," 3X
    sub(/  */, ",");sub(/  */, ",");sub(/  */, ",")
    # use string literal match targets ("\t") 
    sub("\t", ",\\t")
    # match any string literal "\t" and change to "\\t" 
    #   (which will display as "\t" in the output)
    gsub("\t", "\\t")
    print}'
```

**output**

```
blabla.xml,36,14601,lllpxl01,\t\t\tselect 1 from dual
```

if the `\t\t\t` is meant to be 3 `<TAB>` chars

```
echo "blabla.xml 36 14601    lllpxl01\t\t\tselect 1 from dual" \
| awk '{
    # change a consecutive run of space chars to a single "," 3X
    sub(/  */, ",");sub(/  */, ",");sub(/  */, ",");
    # change the first reg-exp match for `/\t/` to display as ",\t"
    sub(/\t/, ",\\t")
    # match any <TAB> reg-exp (/\t/) and and change to "\\t" 
    #   (which will display as "\t" in the output)
    gsub(/\t/, "\\t"); print}'
```

**alt output** (the same, really)

```
blabla.xml,36,14601,lllpxl01,\t\t\tselect 1 from dual
```

In both examples, I'm using `"\\t"` to output a literal '\t' which, will be interpreted by your shell and most other programs as a `<TAB>` char. With these subtle(ish) distinctions,  you can pick an choose the output your need.

Of course this is a very fragile solution, in that you will probably realize "oh I need 2 more fixes" that will change the steps you need to use.

Instead, I highly recommend going back the the source of your input data, and get it to output exactly what you need, OR at least so the output is in a state that a single `gsub(/  */, ",")` (or similar) will give you usable results.

IHTH.

Comment: Awesome answers. IHTH was closer to what I want. I can use this as it is, would be nice if the tabs remained as actual tabs. I love one-liners :)

Answer (score 0):

Some like this:

```
awk '{sub(/ /,",");sub(/ /,",");sub(/ +/,",");sub(/\\t/,",&")}1'
blabla.xml,36,14601,lllpxl01,\t\t\tselect 1 from dual
```

If the  `\t` in your post is `tab`, then:

```
awk '{sub(/ /,",");sub(/ /,",");sub(/ +/,",");sub(/\t/,",&")}1' file
blabla.xml,36,14601,lllpxl01,                   select 1 from dual
```